# can't build the docker image with error saying image not found

Tags: docker

I am trying to build a docker image from [public repository](https://github.com/dockerfile/ghost).  Actually I had built it successfully before, today I wanted to update the image to latest one, so I removed the older image, and tried to pull the new image.

However, when I tried

```
$ docker pull dockerfile/ghost
Pulling repository dockerfile/ghost
FATA[0001] Error: image dockerfile/ghost:latest not found
```

I can't really understand why it doesn't work, it is supposed to be working.

Answer (score 3):

[This is what you need](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/library/ghost/)
Use **docker pull ghost**.

Comment: Thanks, Chandan, how you tried it. I just tried it and found " docker run -d -p 8080:2368 –name website -v /home/ss/servers/website:/var/lib/ghost ghost "  doesn't work for me if I want to point the external files to the container, the container can be created but always not alive

Comment: From the question, it looks like you were having trouble to get the image build/download. So docker pull ghost shall work. And i just tried to pull the image and ran it. It runs like a charm.Migrations: Up to date at version 003
Ghost is running in development... Listening on 0.0.0.0:2368 
Url configured as: http://localhost:2368

Comment: Hi, Chandan, the image can be built and container is running ok if I run a simple ghost server with content inside the container. However, if i point the image to the existing content on my host, it doesn't work

Comment: Any more info on why it stops? Can you pass docker logs container_id

Comment: This is the logs.   " Migrations: Up to date at version 003
Ghost is running in development... 
Listening on 127.0.0.1:2368 
Url configured as: http://localhost:2368"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @Chandan. I followed his advice to find the problem through

**docker logs container_id**

Firstly, the error is

> ERROR: casper cannot be activated because it is not currently
>   installed.

so I downloaded the casper and put it into the theme folder.

Secondly, the error is

> Migrations: Up to date at version 003 Ghost is running in
>   development...  Listening on 127.0.0.1:2368  Url configured as:
>   http://localhost:2368

because the ghost server is running in the development mode.so I make it as production mode.

Thirdly, by making it into the production mode, there is a error

> ERROR: Unable to access Ghost's content path:

so I followed the instruction to  edit /path/to/ghost/blog/config.js and copy the paths section from development to production. Then restart the container.

```
docker restart some-ghost
```

at last it works

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
docker pull dockerfile/ubuntu
```

with

```
docker pull ubuntu
```

Similarly in Dockerfile for base image pull, replace

```
FROM dockerfile/ubuntu
```

with

```
FROM ubuntu
```

> Change ubuntu to any other image name you require